# Can I use a remote user to log in into a remote SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, remote

Can I use the administrator user of a remote (no domain or anything like that) Windows Server to log in into the SQL Server running on that same machine? That would be, using the same credentials, user and password, as I use when I connect to that server with Remote Desktop.

Is there anything special I should do for that?

I'm talking about SQL Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could find, there's no way to use the Windows credentials to log into SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

If the username and password that you are logging into your local computer with, are the same as a username and password that exist on the SQL Server then yes.

If the username and/or password are different then no, you can't specify a Windows account and password when connecting using Windows Authentication.

Comment: Well, I don't care about using Windows Authentication or SQL Authentication (actually, I wasn't even trying with Windows Authentication), but I do care about using the same account, the same credentials, user and password, as when using remote desktop.

Comment: But Windows Authentication is exactly what you asked for. Otherwise you would have to set up an SQL username/password combo that *looked* the same, but would not actually *be* the same

Comment: Farseeker, I've corrected my question now. I want to log in into SQL Server with my SQL Management Studio using the same credentials I use for logging into that machine with Remote Desktop.

Comment: That would be the same Windows account using Windows Authentication.  The only way to do that would be to create an account on the machine you are running SSMS on with the same username and password as the account on the other machine.  Then run SSMS under that account by either logging onto your machine with this account, or by launching SSMS under this account by using the runas function of Windows.

Comment: So, there's no way to connect to a SQL server using SQL Auth without having to create a SQL Auth user, but using the Windows user I already have at that machine.

Comment: No there not.  Windows accounts and SQL Accounts are completely separate.